# Absolute path PHP

Tags: php

I have a problem because i can´t work my images or css when my site is like www.site.com/shop

Situation:
I have these folders inc  img css js

In my root documents i have  and in this include i have all the styles.css, scripts and metadata.

So far so good, all the documents work when they are in root document but now i have a new folder called shop where i am putting code to make a store.

mysite/shop

How can i call from the shop/index.php all my images, and css, js and inc ?

I want to avoid using ../img/bla.jpg or ../inc/header.php also because when i include the footer or menu i can´t find the images.

Thanks for all the help.

Comment: Is this a custom site?  Did you do all of your PHP from scratch or are you using some web framework?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A direct way to access those from HTML would be to provide the / absolute path that refers to the root of your site ie `http://mysite.com/`. For example:

`<img src="/img/image.jpg"/>` would point to a folder `http://mysite.com/img/image.jpg` no matter what your current url structure is.

There are some (quite common) pitfalls of using this inside **server-side** PHP to reference files from the root of your site(it will try to read files from the root of your drive on UNIX systems for example) but inside **client-side** HTML code the absolute root `/` works like a charm, getting the right `http://mysite.com/` absolute path.

Comment: And when developing in wamp, what should to?

Comment: If you use this in HTML output ie an image tag then just do the `/` notation, IF however you try to read a file with PHP use a variable to store the working directory and use that to pre-pend your path like `$file = $rootpath.'/path/to/some/file.php'`.

Comment: When i am in mysite.com/shop how can i include that config file that there is in the root? i need to make an include ../config.php right?

Comment: Yes, that is one of the safest ways of including a file that is on the root of your site from a subdirectory inside PHP.

Comment: There is no way to avoid using ../ ? Thanks for everything

Comment: There are alternative ways of doing that, however that is the simplest. One of the favored approach is to define a global variable that would hold the root path of the project, for example `$root = c:\dev\project\path\ ` and then use that to include files like: `require($root.'file.php')`

Answer (score 2):

You can also prepend the paths with a forward slash to make them relative to root:

```
<img src="/somefolder/relative/to/root/image.jpg" />
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm thinking you could use [BASE](http://www.w3.org/TR/html40/struct/links.html#h-12.4):

```
<base href="http://mysite.com/shop"/>
```

Which changes the root path that all of your files will use.

Comment: We use it, and it works perfectly. Only thing is to set this value from server side.